# Using A Limited Number of Threads With Graceful Timeout Inside a Class

Tags: python, multithreading, class

How can I use only a set number of threads within a class function, while still timing out gracefully if a particular request fails to complete? Here is what I have so far:

```
from threading import Thread
import random
import time
class ExampleClass():
    
    

    def __init__(self, arglist):
        """
        Initializes...
        """
        self.arglist = arglist
        self.threadlist = []
        self.resultlist = []
        
    
    
    def run(self):
        i = 0
        

        for r in self.arglist:
            try: 
                print("one", i)
                i += 1
                t = Thread(target=self.waitfunc, args=(r,))
                t.daemon = True
                self.threadlist.append(t)
                t.start()            
            except Exception, e:
                print("in multithread error block", e)
                pass
        j = 0
        for g in self.threadlist:
            print("two", j)
            j += 1
            g.join(5)
            if g.isAlive():
                print ("error joining thread", j)
                pass


    def waitfunc(self, a):
        
        try:
            result = None
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1,60))
            result = a ** 2
        
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        
        finally:
            self.resultlist.append(result)    

e = ExampleClass(range(1000))
```

As you can see, my current example spawns a thread for each object in arglist. While that's probably ok for my reproducible example above, for a task like a web **scraper** I would like something similar to the above, but with the ability to limit the number of requests being made at any one time. One possible route would be to use queues as in [this example](http://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/):

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
 
def do_stuff(q):
  while True:
    print q.get()
    q.task_done()
 
q = Queue(maxsize=0)
num_threads = 10
 
for i in range(num_threads):
  worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q,))
  worker.setDaemon(True)
  worker.start()
 
for x in range(100):
  q.put(x)
 
q.join()
```

I am unsure, however, how to modify this example to (a) return a result and (b) make sure that if a task fails to complete in a timely manner that the thread times out rather than hanging forever. One way to return a result seems to be to have a second done queue to add results to, as in [this example](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/), but I am unsure how to then join both queues in timely error tolerant manner.  Finally, my understanding was that the advantage of my first example where the threading occurs within the class object without queues is that because it does not use queues the arglist objects do not have to be either pickled or copied in memory, which saves time. Is that correct or erroneous?

Comment: Since you are setting a fixed number of threads, why do you want them to timeout?  Wouldn't it just be a matter of making sure that the tasks they are executing time out?

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes, you're correct. I guess I was thinking you would simply stop the thread and start another if a worker timed out.

Comment: when you say "worker timed out" it implies to me that the thread itself is unresponsive.  Personally, I think it's cleaner to let the threads live and just timeout on the requests.  It's definitely less complicated.

Comment: I guess. The main thing I'm unsure of is how using queues inside a class interacts with memory usage / needing to pickle objects. My understanding is that queues use pickling while my first example does not. I'm also unsure what happens when you pass a queue to several different threads, i.e. what's actually being copied.

Comment: I looked for some documentation about this and the docs say multiprocessing.Queue uses pickling but I can't find anything similar in the Queue.Queue docs.  Do you have a reference?  Also, keep in mind you are not putting your threads in the Queue.  As long as your objects on the queue are simple, this shouldn't matter and it's something you can override based on the docs.  What is the concern exactly?